# How to create a resourse of API-Gatway authorizer, in serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I using a cognito authorizer im my API, and using serverless to configure the api. For add a autorizer to a funcitions, i found this code ([How to configure my Serverless YML to use my API Gateway Authorizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56971070/how-to-configure-my-serverless-yml-to-use-my-api-gateway-authorizer)):

```
teste:
  handler: handler.teste
  memorySize: 128
  events:
    - http:
        path: teste
        method: get
        authorizer:
          name: api-authorizer
          arn: arn:aws:cognito-idp:XXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXX:userpool/XXXXXXX_XXXXXXX
          type: token
```

this code works very nice, but i need repeat a same authorizer in multiple functions, and using this code, for each function a new authorizer is create.... this is a waste of resourse and generete a mess in AWS console

For resolve this problem i try this:

```
teste:
  handler: handler.teste
  memorySize: 128
  events:
    - http:
        path: teste
        method: get
        authorizer: myAuthorizer


resources:
  Resources:
    myAuthorizer:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
      Properties:
        Name: "testing"
        arn: arn:aws:cognito-idp:XXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXX:userpool/XXXXXXX_XXXXXXX
        authorizerId:
          Ref: api-authorizer
```

But don't have success, and i didn't found documentations or guides for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it's not big of a deal to have the authorizer section repeated. In my case, it makes sense to have it repeated since we are using scopes.

```
listItems:
  handler: handler.listItems
  events:
    - http:
        method: get
        path: /list-items
        authorizer:
          arn: ${self:custom.vars.${self:custom.vars.stage}.userPoolArn}
          scopes:
            - transactions/read              

writeItem:
  handler: handler.writeItem
  events:
    - http:
        method: post
        path: /write-item
        authorizer:
          arn: ${self:custom.vars.${self:custom.vars.stage}.userPoolArn}
          scopes:
            - transactions/write
```

But if you would like to share an authorizer it's here.

```
resources:
  Resources:
    ApiGatewayAuthorizer:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
      Properties:
        AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 300
        IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
        Name: Cognito
        RestApiId:
          Ref: YourApiGatewayName
        Type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
        ProviderARNs:
          - arn:aws:cognito-idp:${self:provider.region}:xxxxxx:userpool/abcdef

functions:
  deleteUser:
      ...
    events:
      - http:
          path: /users/{userId}
          ...
          # Provide both type and authorizerId
          type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS # TOKEN or REQUEST or COGNITO_USER_POOLS, same as AWS Cloudformation documentation
          authorizerId:
            Ref: ApiGatewayAuthorizer # or hard-code Authorizer ID
```

Reference:
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#share-authorizer

Comment: I didn't think that it creates a lot of resources when the authorizer section is repeated

Comment: I think what you are missing is the type `type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS` under the events section of the function.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a certain type of API Gateway Authorizer, a [Cognito Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html). These are specifically for authenticating users from a Cognito User Pool.

To use a Cognito Authorizer with [serverless](https://github.com/serverless/serverless) your `serverless.yml` could look something like this:

```
teste:
  handler: handler.teste
  memorySize: 128
  events:
    - http:
        path: teste
        method: get
        authorizer:
          arn: arn:aws:cognito-idp:XXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXX:userpool/XXXXXXX_XXXXXXX
```

You aren't required to send the authorizer name or type when using a Cogntio Authorizer. Additionally, the arn should be pointing to your Cognito User Pool, which the one in your example appears to be.

Checkout the serverless documentation topic on [custom authorizers](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#http-endpoints-with-custom-authorizers) if you want any more information or examples.